# Updated something and now Angular project won't start up

Tags: angular

My project was working fine, now I'm getting massive errors when I try to start it up. Not sure what I did, but I suspect I upgraded something I shouldn't have.

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.22",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.43",
    "firebase": "^3.6.4",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "ng2-completer": "^0.4.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker": "0.0.5",
    "oauthsimple": "0.0.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
    "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
```

error message in browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__.Version is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (version.js:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ed93a58…:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:104104)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ed93a58…:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:4390)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ed93a58…:52)
    at Obj..........
```

and when I npm start, my cmd line console says:

```
[default] C:\app_path\node_modules\@angular\router\src\router_module.d.ts:9:104
    Module '"C:/app_path/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'NgProbeToken'.
[default] C:\app_path\node_modules\@angular\router\src\version.d.ts:13:10
    Module '"C:/app_path/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Version'.
```

and finally, when I try to build I get miles of red text which starts with this:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/css/sub.scss
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\app_path\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?sourcemap&minimize'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at loadLoader (C:\app_path\node_mod..........
```

Also just noticed this error trying to run npm start:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourcemap!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourcemap!./src/assets/css/sub.scss
Module build failed:
@include md-core();
        ^
      No mixin named md-core

Backtrace:
        stdin:8
      in C:\app_path\src\assets\css\sub.scss (line 8, column 10)
 @ ./src/assets/css/sub.scss 4:14-191
 @ multi styles
```

I deleted node_modules and run npm install, but it didn't change anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: So did you try going back to before the change? FYI Dropbox is [not really version control](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170791/dropbox-as-a-version-control-tool).

Comment: Actually what I did was install Git and make a commit, and I stopped sharing that dropbox folder. But I only did it yesterday, and it was actually immediately after my Initial commit that I noticed it was broken. Meaning my only backup is a broken copy :(

Comment: Try deleting node_modules folder and running npm install again

Comment: Yup, did that a bunch of times.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: I did! I deleted everything and started over.